# How to properly insert a flash object into a modal HTML dialog

Tags: html, css, flash, modal-dialog

I have a page that works with a modal, shown when a link is clicked. It works ok with text, but I can't figure a way to make it work properly with a shockwave object. When embedded in the code, the flash element shows up all the time instead of showing only when clicking at the modal. What should I do to keep the flash hidden at first, being shown only inside the modal window that is revealed after clicking the link?

Here is de HTML excerpt:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>MODAL</title>
    <meta name="description" content="responsive layout demos">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/left-fluid.css">

     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header></header>

    <div class="columns-container">

        <div class="left-column">

        <div id="modal-window">
            <a href="#openModal" class="botao"><h3 class="botao"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; click here to see the modal with flash</h3></a>
        </div>

           <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
              <div> 
                 <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                 <P>THIS IS SHOWN IN THE MODAL</P>
                 <!--THIS IS NOT -> --><embed width="500" height="300" src="flash/stuff.swf"> 
              </div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
    }

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    }

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 3% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    }

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    }

.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
    }
```

Comment: FYI Flash doesn't run on a lot of devices now. You would be better to convert that file to html5 ready.

Comment: I would love to do that, but I can't. Also, this code will run in a private network with known browsers that only work on the intranet, so that's not an issue for now.

Comment: Which browsers did you test this in? All same result? Also what happens if at `<!--THIS IS NOT -> -->` section, you use an **i-frame** pointing to an html container/embeder of the swf? Does using **innerHTML** to update the opened modal window help? As a final solution, quick test a different lightbox tool just to be sure about your current code...

Comment: I'm using Firefox, Edge and Chrome. With the corrections from mlegg below it works in the last two with the need of an iframe but not in Firefox. I'll try your suggestions to see what happens and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `<embed width="500" height="300" src="flash/stuff.swf">`  code add this at the end before the >:

```html
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
       pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
```

you have 2 unclosed `<div>` tags, add `</div>` under each of these `<div class="columns-container">` and `<div class="left-column">`

Comment: This is pretty close, works in Chrome and Edge but not Firefox. The object is shown even with the modal closed, any idea on why?

Comment: I'm not sure because I use Firefox mainly, Do you have the Flash plugin for Firefox? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-flash-plugin-view-videos-animations-games

Comment: yes, the object works normally... except it doesnt hide inside de modal like in the other browsers.